# ECS jenkins container error touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, logging, amazon-ecs, docker-volume

ECS jenkins container  error touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied

What permission I need to add here  ???

```yaml
  JenkinsTaskDefinition:
Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
Properties:
  Family: !Sub jenkins-ec2-ecs-hadr
  ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: jenkins
      Cpu: 1024
      Memory: 2048
      Essential: true
      Image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 8080
          HostPort: 8080
          Protocol: tcp
      MountPoints:
        - SourceVolume: jenkinsdata
          ContainerPath: /var/jenkins_home
          readonly: false
        LogDriver: awslogs
        Options:
          awslogs-group: !Ref CloudwatchLogsGroup
          awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs-jenkins-hadr
  Volumes:
    - Host:
          SourcePath: "/data-jenkins/"
      Name: jenkinsdata 
      Commands:
```

ECS jenkins container  error touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied

Comment: >Exit Code 143 happens due to multiple reasons and one of them is related to Memory/GC issues.

Comment: I got it working however now it is giving   touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied

Comment: did you find the solution for this? @ShartulKumar

Comment: It is working now, got it fixed